# Python: Convert local time to another time zone

Tags: python, time

I want to convert the current time to +0900 in Python.

What's the appropriate way to do this (assuming in the time module)?

I've read this isn't included with Python and you have to use something like pytz.

I don't want to change it on a server basis or globally, just in this one instance.

Comment: related: [How do you convert a datetime/timestamp from one timezone to another timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977563/python-how-do-you-convert-a-datetime-timestamp-from-one-timezone-to-another-tim/67354610#67354610). Note: with Python 3.9, use [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`datetime` module](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) instead.  Adapted from http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo.fromutc

```
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime

class FixedOffset(tzinfo):
    def __init__(self, offset):
        self.__offset = timedelta(hours=offset)
        self.__dst = timedelta(hours=offset-1)
        self.__name = ''

    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return self.__offset

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return self.__name

    def dst(self, dt):
        return self.__dst

print datetime.now()
print datetime.now(FixedOffset(9))
```

Gives:

```
2011-03-12 00:28:32.214000
2011-03-12 14:28:32.215000+09:00
```

When I run it (I'm UTC-0500 for another day, then DST begins)

Comment: Thanks. Great answer! You can also add `print datetime.utcnow()` to show full picture of times - your local, UTC and shifted time.

Answer (score 28):

## Example for converting data from UTC to IST

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"

# Current time in UTC
now_utc = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))
print now_utc.strftime(format)
Output: 2015-05-18 10:02:47 UTC+0000

# Convert to Asia/Kolkata time zone
now_asia = now_utc.astimezone(timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
print now_asia.strftime(format)
Output: 2015-05-18 15:32:47 IST+0530
```

Comment: Thanks. You say 'Asia/Kolkata' but how can I see a list of acceptables timezones string, for example Asia/Japan?

Comment: I mean is there a command withoin pytz that print all the timezone strings avilable?

Comment: found myself `print( pytz.all_timezones)`

Comment: `now_asia = datetime.now(timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))` also works.

Comment: This does not work well for future times that are in DST or vice versa. DST is not taken into account

Answer (score 15):

> I want to convert the current time to +0900 in Python
>   ...
>   I don't want to change it on a server basis or globally, just in this one instance.

To get current time for `+0900` timezone offset from UTC:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

current_time_in_utc = datetime.utcnow()
result = current_time_in_utc + timedelta(hours=9)
```

Don't use aware datetime objects unless you also use pytz library otherwise you might get wrong results due to DST transitions and other timezone changes. If you need to do some arithmetics on datetime objects; convert them to UTC first.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed, too. Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to know what is wrong with the answer so that it got the downvote, so that the answer can be improved.

Comment: Works perfectly for IST, just use `hours=5, minutes=30`

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you can use pytz and other external modules, this is a more straight forward solution

```
pip install pytz tzlocal
```

then

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import pytz
from tzlocal import get_localzone

#timezones
local = get_localzone()
utc = pytz.utc
cet = timezone('CET')

#get now time in different zones
print(datetime.now(local))
print(datetime.now(cet))
print(datetime.now(utc))

#convert local time now to CET
print(datetime.now(local).astimezone(cet))
print(datetime.now(cet).astimezone(utc))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `datetime` module, there is an abstract base class called `tzinfo` which controls how `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.time` handle time zones.  You basically derive your own class to control the time zone interpretation.  I have never personally used it, so I can't say much more about it.

Unfortunately, the only time zone controls I see directly in the `time` module work on a global basis, I believe.