# Epoch time is one hour out from UTC, should be UTC+1

Tags: python, datetime, time, epoch

I have written a module that generates a percentage chance of events happening during a specific time. My database has a timestamp of when events are generated. I am converting the timetamp which is in y-m-d h-m-s format into epoch time. The epoch time that I am getting is in UTC (GMT) time where as my time zone is GMT + 1.

An example as follows:

My first database entry is at 10:13:36 which has an epoch time of 1397211216, when I attempt to get the epoch time for this entry from within my code the epoch time that is returned is 1397207617 (09:13:36). My code is below, I know there is an issue with how my epoch time is defined but I can't figure out how to alter it to get the correct time.

```
def getPercentageDuringTime(dbName, sensorType, beginningTime, endTime):
    count = 0
    reading = [i [1]for i in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM " + dbName + " WHERE sensor = '" + sensorType + "' ")] 
    readingtime = [i [2] for i in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM " + dbName + " WHERE sensor = '" + sensorType + "' ")] 
    for i in range(len(reading)):
        pattern = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(readingtime[i], pattern)))
        if ((epoch >= beginningTime) and (epoch <= endTime)):
            count = count + 1
    percentage = count / (len(reading)) * 100

    print (epoch)
    return percentage

print (getPercentageDuringTime('event4312593', 'sound', 1397207617, 1397207616))
```

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280692/python-convert-local-time-to-another-time-zone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`time.mktime()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.mktime) is the inverse of `time.localtime()`, so your parsed time is interpreted as UTC, then moved to your local timezone.

What you need to use here instead is the inverse of `time.gmtime()` instead, which is helpfully hidden in a different module: the [`calendar.timegm()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm):

```
>>> import time, calendar
>>> sample = '2014-04-11 10:13:36'
>>> int(time.mktime(time.strptime(sample, pattern)))
1397207616
>>> int(calendar.timegm(time.strptime(sample, pattern)))
1397211216
```

Instead of using offsets from the UNIX epoch, consider using the `datetime` module instead; it would let you handle the timestamps without having to worry about timezone considerations, which is perfectly fine for your needs:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(sample, pattern)
datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 11, 10, 13, 36)
```

If you have to pass in timestamps (seconds since the UNIX epoch), you can convert those to datetime objects with [`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp):

```
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1397207617)
datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 11, 10, 13, 37)
```

which gives you a `datetime` object by interpreting the value in your machine-local timezone.

Comment: Awesome, .timegm done the job just fine! Thank you for your help