# How do you convert a datetime/timestamp from one timezone to another timezone?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz, timedelta

Specifically, given the timezone of my server (system time perspective) and a timezone input, how do I calculate the system time as if it were in that new timezone (regardless of daylight savings, etc)?

```
import datetime
current_time = datetime.datetime.now() #system time

server_timezone = "US/Eastern"
new_timezone = "US/Pacific"

current_time_in_new_timezone = ???
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you know your origin timezone and the new timezone that you want to convert it to, it turns out to be very straightforward:

1. Make two `pytz.timezone` objects, one for the current timezone and one for the new timezone e.g. `pytz.timezone("US/Pacific")`. You can find a list of all official timezones in `pytz` library: `import pytz; pytz.all_timezones`
2. Localize the datetime/timestamp of interest to the current timezone e.g.

```
current_timezone = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")
localized_timestamp = current_timezone.localize(timestamp)
```

3. Convert to new timezone using `.astimezone()` on the newly localized datetime/timestamp from step 2 with the desired timezone's pytz object as input e.g. `localized_timestamp.astimezone(new_timezone)`.

Done!

As a full example:

```
import datetime
import pytz

# a timestamp I'd like to convert
my_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()

# create both timezone objects
old_timezone = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")
new_timezone = pytz.timezone("US/Pacific")

# two-step process
localized_timestamp = old_timezone.localize(my_timestamp)
new_timezone_timestamp = localized_timestamp.astimezone(new_timezone)

# or alternatively, as an one-liner
new_timezone_timestamp = old_timezone.localize(my_timestamp).astimezone(new_timezone)
```

Bonus: but if all you need is the current time in a specific timezone, you can conveniently pass that timezone directly into datetime.now() to get the current times directly:

```
datetime.datetime.now(new_timezone)
```

When it comes to needing timezones conversions generally, I would strongly advise that one should store all timestamps in your database in UTC, which has no daylight savings time (DST) transition. And as a good practice, one should always choose to enable time zone support (even if your users are all in a single time zone!). This will help you avoid the DST transition problem that plagues so much software today.

Beyond DST, time in software can be generally quite tricky. To get a sense of just how difficult it is to deal with time in software in general, here is a potentially enlightening resource: http://yourcalendricalfallacyis.com

Even a seemingly simple operation as converting a datetime/timestamp into a date can become non-obvious. As [this helpful documentation](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.x/topics/i18n/timezones.html) points out:

> A datetime represents a **point in time**. It’s absolute: it doesn’t depend on anything. On the contrary, a date is a **calendaring concept**. It’s a period of time whose bounds depend on the time zone in which the date is considered. As you can see, these two concepts are fundamentally different.

Understanding this difference is a key step towards avoiding time-based bugs. Good luck.

Comment: (1) if you need the current time, use `datetime.now(server_timezone)` instead of `server_timezone.localize(datetime.now())` (2) consider using `is_dst` parameter (3) You might need `server_timezone.normalize()` after `server_timezone.localize()`, to fix  non-existing local times. See [more details and references in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33310542/4279)

Comment: I believe 'timezone_localized_timestamp' should be 'localized_timestamp' in your example. Or vice versa. Otherwise works perfectly.

Comment: Since this question/answer is a top result, I'd like to inform that `pytz` is not recommended anymore. See: https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html and https://talkpython.fm/episodes/show/271/unlock-the-mysteries-of-time-pythons-datetime-that-is

Answer (score 30):

With Python 3.9, the standard lib has all you need: [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html). pytz is not needed anymore (deprecated; -> [pytz deprecation shim](https://pypi.org/project/pytz-deprecation-shim/)).

Ex:

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

server_timezone = "US/Eastern"
new_timezone = "US/Pacific"

current_time = datetime.now(ZoneInfo(server_timezone)) 

# current_time_in_new_timezone = ???
current_time_in_new_timezone = current_time.astimezone(ZoneInfo(new_timezone))
```

That gives you for example

```
print(current_time.isoformat(timespec='seconds'))
# 2021-10-04T02:42:54-04:00

print(repr(current_time))
# datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 4, 2, 42, 54, 40600, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='US/Eastern'))

print(current_time_in_new_timezone.isoformat(timespec='seconds'))
# 2021-10-03T23:42:54-07:00

print(repr(current_time_in_new_timezone))
# datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 3, 23, 42, 54, 40600, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='US/Pacific'))
```

Comment: For anyone working in python <3.9, you can install a backport of zoneinfo https://pypi.org/project/backports.zoneinfo/

Answer (score 10):

> How do you convert datetime/timestamp from one timezone to another timezone?

There are two steps:

1. **Create an aware datetime objects from the system time and timezone** e.g., to get the current system time in the given timezone:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   from datetime import datetime
   import pytz

   server_timezone = pytz.timezone("US/Eastern")
   server_time = datetime.now(server_timezone) # you could pass *tz* directly
   ```

   Note: [`datetime.now(server_timezone)` works even during ambiguous times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31886808/4279) e.g., during DST transitions while `server_timezone.localize(datetime.now())` may fail (50% chance).

   If you are sure that your input time exists in the server's timezone and it is unique then you could pass `is_dst=None` to assert that:

   ```
   server_time = server_timezone.localize(naive_time, is_dst=None)
   ```

   It raises an exception for invalid times.
   If it is acceptable to ignore upto *a day* error (though typically an error due to DST is around *an hour*) then you could drop `is_dst` parameter:

   ```
   server_time = server_timezone.normalize(server_timezone.localize(naive_time))
   ```

   `.normalize()` is called to adjust non-existing times (local time in the gap, during "spring forward" transitions). If the time zone rules haven't changed; your server shouldn't generate non-existing times. See ["Can I just always set is_dst=True?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32727761/4279)
2. **Convert an aware datetime object to the target timezone `tz`**:

   ```
   tz = pytz.timezone("US/Pacific")
   server_time_in_new_timezone = server_time.astimezone(tz)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to convert a timestamp from one timezone to another, you can use this code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo


from_timezone = ZoneInfo('Europe/Moscow')  # UTC-3
to_timezone = ZoneInfo('Asia/Tbilisi')  # UTC-4

dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, to_timezone)
result_timestamp = int(dt.replace(tzinfo=from_timezone).timestamp())
```

For example, if you take timestamp = 529635600 (1986-14-10 04:00:00 in Moscow) and run this code, you will get result_timestamp = 529639200 (1986-14-10 05:00:00 in Tbilisi).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for mine five cents but as mentioned [FObersteiner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10197418/fobersteiner) starting from python 3.9 the code could simplify:

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

current_time = datetime.now() #system time

# server_timezone = "US/Eastern"
new_timezone = ZoneInfo("US/Pacific")

current_time_in_new_timezone = new_timezone.fromutc(current_time.astimezone(new_timezone))
```

For my personal opinion work with local datetime still quite vague in python but much better than some time ago.