# datetime ignores tzinfo?

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime, pytz, python-dateutil

I'm probably misunderstanding the purpose of tzinfo, but I have a datetime object `dt` I managed to get into this form:

`datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 2, 20, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset('PDT', -7))`

I'm trying to represent the above date from July 2nd 2017 20:00 PDT.

Now, I'd like to convert that time to UTC, but when I do so, it outputs the UTC timestamp for `July 2nd 2017 20:00 UTC`, it doesn't apply the 7 hour difference.

For example:

```
>>> dt.timestamp()
1499025607.0
```

Which is : `Sunday, July 2, 2017 8:00:07 PM`

Also

```
>>> dt.isoformat()
'2017-07-02T20:00:00-00:00:07'
```

I've tried

```
>>> dt.astimezone(pytz.UTC).timestamp()
1499025607.0
```

Notice that's the same timestamp as `dt.timestamp()`

Comment: The key question is: How do you do the conversion?

Comment: possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/31977588/8150371

Comment: @fhossfel Edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [dateutil docs](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html#dateutil.tz.tzoffset), your parameter to the `tzoffset()` function is wrong.

```
tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzoffset('PDT', -7)
```

creates a timezone with an offset of 7 seconds.

```
tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzoffset('PDT', -7*60*60)
```

creates a timezone with an offset of 7 hours.