# 'Europe/Madrid' timezone doesn't match 'Etc/GMT+1'

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, pytz

I'm trying to convert a UTC timestamp to one in the Spanish timezone.

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> import pytz
>>> today = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1573516800)
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 12, 0, 0)

>>> today.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')).timestamp()
1573517700.0

>>> today.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Etc/GMT+1')).timestamp()
1573520400.0
```

I'm surprised that I get different results for `Europe/Madrid` and `Etc/GMT+1`. Why is this? Should `Europe/Madrid` be used differently, or it is possibly a bug?

Comment: have you tried `.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')) `?

Comment: @luigigi Yes. The problem is that `today.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')).timestamp()` returns the same timestamp I started with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UTC Timestamp: The number of seconds since January 1st, 1970 at UTC.

Python datetime: A nice way of seeing this time that is user friendly

The UTC timestamp is not effected by timezones, but the datetime is.

This code takes the given timestamp and converts it to a UTC datetime and a Europe/Madrid timezone.

```py
import datetime as dt
import pytz

# define the old and new timezones
old_timezone = pytz.timezone("UTC")
new_timezone = pytz.timezone("Europe/Madrid")

# get an 'offset-aware' datetime
today = dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1573516800)
my_datetime = old_timezone.localize(today)

# returns datetime in the new timezone
my_datetime_in_new_timezone = my_datetime.astimezone(new_timezone)

print("Old:", str(my_datetime), "\nNew:", str(my_datetime_in_new_timezone), "\nDifference:",
      str(my_datetime - my_datetime_in_new_timezone))
```

Output:

```
Old: 2019-11-12 00:00:00+00:00 
New: 2019-11-12 01:00:00+01:00 
Difference: 0:00:00
```

Code adapted from:
[Python: How do you convert datetime/timestamp from one timezone to another timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977563/python-how-do-you-convert-datetime-timestamp-from-one-timezone-to-another-timez)

Comment: I tried running your code and got `TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'`

Comment: I just fixed that, sorry

Comment: Thanks. But still, how do I get the new timestamp?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity, I added the conversion code at the end.

Comment: Thanks - problem is, that returns the same timestamp we started with

Comment: A timestamp, by definition, is in UTC.  This is described at https://www.unixtimestamp.com/
The python datetime is the only thing that changes with the timezone.
I am editing my answer to make things more clear

Comment: Yes. So, currently, `today` corresponds to: 12th of November, 2019, midnight. I would like the UTC timestamp corresponding to 12th of November, 2019, midnight, in the Spanish timezone. In other words, when in Spain it's midnight on the 12th of November 2019, what's the UTC timestamp?

Comment: Actually, got it - I can just do `new_timezone.localize(today).timestamp()`. Your code helped me get to this, so I'll accept it

Answer (score 6):

A few things:

- `Europe/Madrid` is UTC+1 during standard time, and UTC+2 during summer time (aka daylight saving time).
- `Etc/GMT+1` is UTC-1 for the entire year.  Note the sign is opposite what you might expect.  See the explanation in the [tzdata](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2019c/etcetera#L37-L43) sources, and [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Area).
- Since Madrid is on UTC+1 on the date you gave, you would get the same result for that date if you used `Etc/GMT-1`.  However, I don't recommend that, as you would then later get the wrong result for a date during summer time.
- The `Etc/GMT±X` zones are intended to be used primarily for non-localizable scenarios such as tracking time onboard ships at sea - not for populated locations on land.
- As [Mason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58821173/634824) showed, you should be using the `localize` function rather than `replace` to assign a time zone.  This is covered [in the pytz documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic).

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate this! Lesson learned - read the docs :)