# Date and time with time zone

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

My datetime looks like this:

```
date_time =  "2022-02-17 08:29:36.345374"
```

I want to convert this to another timezone, the API which I am using have a info of for example `userTimeZone = -300`. I tried to search but can't locate that from this `userTimeZone` I can get my timezone time.

Comment: Does [Python: How do you convert a datetime/timestamp from one timezone to another timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977563/python-how-do-you-convert-a-datetime-timestamp-from-one-timezone-to-another-tim) answer your question?

Comment: What does -300 even mean? Is that in minutes, i.e. `-0500`?

Comment: @wwii no sir , I just have info like  -330 , 300 etc ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `timezone` given an offset via `timedelta` (I'm assuming `-300` is in minutes, equivalent to -5 hours):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
>>> tz = timezone(timedelta(minutes=-300))
>>> tz
datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=68400))
>>> tz.tzname(None)
'UTC-05:00'
```

Once you've parsed the `date_time` string (which I'm assuming is in UTC) to an actual datetime:

```
>>> dt = datetime.strptime(date_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 8, 29, 36, 345374)
```

you can apply the offset to see what the local time would be:

```
>>> local = dt.astimezone(tz)
>>> local
datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 17, 3, 29, 36, 345374, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=68400)))
>>> local.isoformat()
'2022-02-17T03:29:36.345374-05:00'
```

Comment: thanks for reply sir , getting this :( \AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

Comment: @voicenob the datetime module contains a datetime class...