# Adjusting time zones using datetime python library

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, python-datetime, pytz

I have the input as a Unix timestamp, which is generated according to UTC time. I need to convert it to human readable time and then adjust the time zones, which is +02:00.

Using the datetime library, I have tried:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

time = "1657893300324"

logtime = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(time)/1000).isoformat(sep=',', timespec='milliseconds')
timezone = pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')
d_aware = timezone.localize(int(logtime))
print(d_aware)
```

error thrown in this process:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2022-07-15,13:55:00.324'
```

Another method:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

time = "1657893300324"

logtime = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(time)/1000).isoformat(sep=',', timespec='milliseconds')
two_hrs = datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
local_time = logtime + two_hrs
print(local_time)
```

error thrown:

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'
```

Answer (score 1):

convert the Unix timestamp to UTC datetime, then change the timezone using `astimezone`.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Berlin')
t = "1657893300324"

logtime = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(t)/1000, timezone.utc)
d_aware = logtime.astimezone(tz)

print(d_aware)
# 2022-07-15 15:55:00.324000+02:00
```

Note: `pytz` is deprecated. Use Python 3.9's zoneinfo instead, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67354610/10197418).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
time = "1657893300324"
timeInSeconds = int(time[0:10])

#add the 2 hours in seconds
timeInSeconds += 3600*2 #there is 3600 seconds in one hour

#and the convert it to a datetime object in python
date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timeInSeconds)

#and print it readable
print(date.isoformat())
#or even better : 
s = str(date.month) + "-" str(date.day) + "-" + str(date.year) + " at " + str(date.hour) + ":" + str(date.minute)
```

Hope it helps ! :)